# Weird background tinge on pygments highlighting in Jekyll blog

Tags: liquid, jekyll, pygments

I'm trying to use pygments to add syntax highlighting to my [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) blog. Now the highlighting works, but it's pitting a weird tint on my code which is best described by looking at the image below.
[image: What it looks like]

I'm using the Github syntax stylesheet but that's not what is causing the issue. I know this because I commented out all the CSS that is responsible for highlighting and the tinge is still there.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this issue?

Here is the code that is responsible for what you see in the image:

```
  <div class="span5 columns">
    {% highlight ruby %}
      # FG2
      FactoryGirl.define do
        factory :user do
          name "Peter Pan"
          email "peter@pan.com"
        end

        factory :team do
          name "The A Team"
          association :user
        end
      end
    {% endhighlight %}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

I was using the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) stylesheet and that was applying the tint to anything wrapped in `code` blocks.

Not sure why I didn't see that in Developer Tools when I checked before posting but ce la vie.